# How to add css class with fade out transition

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do my own notification compoment in my sample Angular application.
I have the following template:

```
  <aside  *ngFor="let message of messages ">
    <div class="notification" style="position:fixed">
      {{message.content}}
    </div>
  </aside>
```

I push new messages through service to the component, so when new message comes it is immidiately showed in above loop.

I would like to make every message visible for 3 seconds.
I need to add a class with fade out transition which is set to 3 seconds.

Comment: can you use Keyframes?

Comment: Yes, I can use them. I have tried with them, but I couldn't find why does not work.

Comment: Can you post your css?

Comment: Please post example css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `keyframes` structure.

```
@keyframes fadeout {
from {opacity:1;}
to {opacity:0;}
}

.notification {
animation: fadeout 3s
}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer as a correct solution shortly. There is the limitation set to 5 minutes.

Comment: @tylkonachwile sure! glad i could help :)